# Access 2016 Using combobox in SQL query

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to create a query that uses  the selection of a single combobox as part of the WHERE clause.

The query:

```
SELECT Database.Contact_ID, Database.[Full Name], Database.[Job Title], 
Institution.Institution, Database.Email, Database.[Email 2], Database.[Work 
phone], Database.[Work phone 2], Database.Mobile, Database.Notes, Database. 
[Date created], [Keyword Junction].Keywords, Database.[Record Type]

FROM Institution INNER JOIN (Keywords INNER JOIN ([Database] INNER JOIN 
[Keyword Junction] ON Database.[Contact_ID] = [Keyword Junction].Contact_ID) 
ON Keywords.Keyword_ID = [Keyword Junction].Keywords.Value) ON 
Institution.ID = Database.InstitutionLookup

WHERE ((Keywords.Keyword)=[Forms]![Keyword Search Mk 2]![SelectKeyword]);
```

The 'Keyword Search Mk 2' form is a simple pop out form with the combobox that allows the user to select the desired keyword. I can select the keyword in the form but when I run the search the results are empty.

The previous WHERE clause was:

```
WHERE ((Keywords.[Keyword]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Keyword Search Mk 2]! 
[SelectKeyword]  & "*");
```

This had the same issue. I've also tried specifying the column number e.g.

```
WHERE ((Keywords.[Keyword]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Keyword Search Mk 2]! 
[SelectKeyword].[Columns](1)  & "*");
```

Again with no luck.

Appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: How are you running the query? (As this can affect whether or not the parameters are evaluated as form controls). Is the `Keyword` field the bound column of your combobox?

Comment: @LeeMac The keyword field wasn't bound as you suggest, knew there was an easy solution I was missing. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome Tony, I have added the solution as an answer so that this question may be marked as resolved for others viewing.

Comment: Thanks apologies I meant to do this, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the conversation in the comments, when a record is selected, the value of the ComboBox control will be equal to value of the field in the Row Source which corresponds to the Bound Column number.

For example, if your Row Source dataset contains three fields and the Bound Column is set to `2`, the value of the second field in the dataset will be returned by the expression `[Forms]![YourFormName]![YourComboBox]`.